# Is it plagiarism to use a jquery plugin for a school project?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery plugin called FullCalendar to assist with generating a weekly schedule in a website for a school project. Would that be considered plagiarism, as it has javascript that handles most of the tedious work?

Comment: it depends on the project description. If you have to use your **own** javascript, then yes, if you have just to handle a problem, then probably not.

Comment: I'd say, it depends what your teacher wants you to learn ;) From a professional point of view, I would definitely go for some existing plugin and tweak it to fit my needs rather than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It's not plagiarism if you don't try to pass it off as your own work. If the plugin just helps with a minor issue and you credit it that is probably fine. But if the assignment is to implement specifically the functionality that the plugin does for you then obviously that won't help you pass.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: As a developer you should be able to use any instruments you want/find (that are free), if not requested otherwise I would say it's OK - you still have to implement the plug-in and build everything around it

Comment: TALK TO THE PROFESSOR :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the assignment is to hand-craft every single line of code...
**no**, it's not plagiarism,   even more, it's encouraged.
 Most of the code you can find *in the wild* is Open-Sourced, developed and maintained by friendly and smart people, and if you're not restricted by some mean licence, go for it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software

Answer (score 0):

Not its not unless it is said that not to use any plugin you can use any plugin that is openly available and have no license issue means they plugin owner allow you to use his/her api without any charges

Comment: Downvoting cause this answer does not add any value to the already posted answer.